# Automatically generating pages in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

This is more of just a general question; Im wondering if anyone has a link or can recommend a book that has information on how to auto generate pages in Angular 2.

More specifically what Im hoping to accomplish is, based on information in my backend(let's say I have 2 fruit objects) I want to just generate a new page for each of those objects. Thank you.

Comment: If a page is a 'url' you should check how Angular manage routing. Also, try to think every part of a website/application like a component and the concept of 'page' could be just a component that renders html at a specific URL.

Comment: Hi Gunter, I should have clarified. Im hoping to take an HTML template and populate it with different data, generating a new unique URL for each "page".

Comment: @fjcero Thank you for the info, I will definitely look more into routing.

Comment: In Angular2 you usually just do an HTTP request to the server and let Angular generate the view (HTML) based on the returned data (like using `*ngFor`). Check out http://angular.io

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the info. I finally found what I was looking for here: [Router Configuration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)